# JQuery show/hide divs in order

Tags: jquery, hide, show

I am using the jQuery show/hide effect from hovering on a div to show and hide several divs, this works fine, the problem is I want the divs to show and hide in a staggered order not all at once, so if I hover over #a, I want to see #b in 200ms, #c in 400ms and #d in 600ms, then when I hover out I want them to hide in the revrese order?
I have a fiddle of what I have so far...

```
<div id="one">
<div id="a"></div>
<div id="b"></div>
<div id="c"></div>
<div id="d"></div>
</div>

$("#b, #c, #d").hide();
$("#a,#b, #c, #d").hover(function () {
$("#b, #c, #d").show();
}, function () {
$("#b, #c, #d").hide();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bloodygeese/9LQAu/

also I want to replicate this across the site so it would be good to know how to only have this affect the div I'm hovering not the other one as well, * see fiddle

Comment: Is [***THIS***](http://jsfiddle.net/9LQAu/6/) what you're trying to do ?

Answer (score 1):

Here, i've got an idea:

```
$('div').on('hide-on-by-one', function () {

    var prev = $(this).prev('div');

    $(this).hide('slow', function () {
        prev.trigger('hide-on-by-one');
    });
});

/* trigger the event on your last element */

$('div:last').trigger('hide-on-by-one');
```

Answer (score 0):

I've changed the IDs to classes since there seems to be multiple elements with the same value

```
$('.one').each(function(){
    var $this = $(this)
    var $oths = $this.children('div').not('.a').hide();
    $this.children('.a').hover(function () {
        $oths.each(function(idx){
            var $item = $(this);

            clearTimeout($item.data('hideTimer'))

            var timer = setTimeout(function(){
                $item.show();
            }, (idx + 1) * 200);
            $item.data('showTimer', timer);
        })
    }, function () {
        hideOthers($oths)
    });

    $oths.hover(function(){
        $oths.each(function(idx){
            clearTimeout($(this).data('hideTimer'))
        })
    }, function(){
        hideOthers($oths)
    })

})


function hideOthers($oths){
    var len  = $oths.length;
    $oths.each(function(idx){
        var $item = $(this);

        clearTimeout($item.data('showTimer'))

        var timer = setTimeout(function(){
            $item.hide();
        }, (len - idx) * 200);

        $item.data('hideTimer', timer);
    })
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/7AbDf/)